# How to randomize string values in table without rand() and CASE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I frequently build dummy data sets to use with dashboards and I often need to populate all rows in a table with one of 5-10 string values. So far I've used CASE statement and rand() function but it's time-consuming and not scalable. I wonder if there's a quicker, alternative way to achieve the same.

Note: I don't want data to be fully random because it will likely result in a more-or-less equal spread of all options. Ideally, I'd like to have some control over how frequently particular values appear - e.g. have 1-2 dominant options, some very infrequent value, and the rest spread somewhere in between.

So far i've used something like this:

```
UPDATE dataset.table  
SET 
  Account_Industry = CASE
    WHEN rand() > 0.91 THEN 'E-Commerce'
    WHEN rand() BETWEEN 0.85 AND 0.91 THEN 'Healthcare'
    WHEN rand() BETWEEN 0.7 AND 0.85 THEN 'Financial Services'
    WHEN rand() BETWEEN 0.52 AND 0.7 THEN 'Manufacturing'
    WHEN rand() BETWEEN 0.42 AND 0.52 THEN 'Retail'
    WHEN rand() BETWEEN 0.07 AND 0.42 THEN 'Technology'
    ELSE 'Education'
    END
WHERE true
```